# Python: TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, function, object, typeerror

I'm new to python, and I'm having trouble with some code. I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__' at line 32
```

I can't figure out what's going on. From what I've seen on the internet, it means something about using a function as a list, but I can't figure that out with my code. My code is

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python


import random


def genFirstGen():
    print "First Generation"
    generation = []
    for chromosomecounter in range(0, 20):
        chromosome = []
        fitness = 0
        for genecounter in range(0, 10):
            chromosome.append(random.randrange(0, 2))
        for genecounter in range(0, 10):
            if (chromosome[genecounter] == 1):
                fitness += 1
        chromosome.append(fitness)
        generation.append(chromosome)
        print gene
    return generation


def FindMostFit(generation):
    failedset = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    highestfitness = 0
    mostfit = 0
    fitparents = []
    gene = []
    for fitcounter in range(0, 10):
        for chromosomecounter in range(0, 20):
            chromosome = [generation[chromosomecounter]] #  The error is here.
            fitness  = chromosome[10]
            highestfitness = 0
            if (fitness > highestfitness):
                highestfitness = fitness
                mostfit = chromosomecounter

        fitparents.append(generation[mostfit])
        generation[mostfit] = failedset
    return fitparents


def BreedMostFit(Parents):
    Mother = Parents(random.randrange(0, 10))
    Father = Parents(random.randrange(0, 10))
    child = []
    for genecounter in range(0, 5):
        parentgenetaken = random.randrange(0, 2)
        if (parentgenetaken == 1):
            child.append(Mother[genecounter * 2])
            child.append(Mother[(genecounter * 2) + 1])
        else:
            child.append(Father[genecounter * 2])
            child.append(Father[(genecounter * 2) + 1])
    return child


def Generation2():
    newgeneration = []
    for gencounter in range(0, 20):
        newgeneration.append(BreedMostFit(FindMostFit(genFirstGen)))
    return newgeneration

def GenerationFunction(parentgen):
    generation = []
    for gencounter in range(0, 20):
        generation.append(BreedMostFit(FindMostFit(parentgen)))
    return generation

GenerationFunction(Generation2())
```

I'm at my wits end. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Feel like sharing the traceback?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you maybe write which line generates the error and on what call? Your code is quite long and it's not clear where the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

On line 62 you pass `genFirstGen` function into `FindMostFit`

```
newgeneration.append(BreedMostFit(FindMostFit(genFirstGen)))
```

Later on line 32 you index it. I guess you wanted to call the function and pass its results instead. So replace line 62 with

```
newgeneration.append(BreedMostFit(FindMostFit(genFirstGen())))
```

Answer (score 1):

What's passed to `FindMostFit` is `genFirstGen` function itself, not an output from called `genFirstGen()`.

This:

`newgeneration.append(BreedMostFit(FindMostFit(genFirstGen)))`

Should look like this:

`newgeneration.append(BreedMostFit(FindMostFit(genFirstGen())))`.